# Article list and opening in page

Tags: usability

I have a list of articles that the client wants to open/reveal in page rather than going to another page. He also wants to do this for an inbox. So it looks cooler and forward thinking.

Im trying to get a good enough reason not to do this other than it doesnt feel right and it may not be the best experience for mobile.

Are there any usability/UX issues that anyone can see with this?

Comment: It's still little blury, can you be more specific? Like what those articles' are for and how much content would it have? For Inbox you can have live example of Facebook Messages.

Comment: Actually it totally depends, it's fine if it does not have long-long content in (any) article posts. As if so, it will be too much of scrolling.

Comment: But you will surely have issues with SEO, just as @James Wilkinson Mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like they are trying to mimic Feedly and Gmail interfaces for reading, this is not a bad thing.

However performance of the application is something to keep in mind. If you don't have the development resources to serve each of those articles via AJAX functionality so clicking on the article loads the article inline then you have a major problem. Loading all that content on load is a poor experience, slow, and will destroy your SEO for Google seeing your page as not performant.

Another perspective to have is accessibility, a screen reader will have a hay-day trying to parse what to read first and how to interact, make sure you develop with `aria` labels in mind, and using semantic HTML.

As to the UI, I don't mind this type of UI however I use this a power user skipping articles via `j` and `k` keys like in Feedly. Take a look at feedly and draw some parallels through that, instead of through gmail.